# Is the class of non regular languages is closed under complementation?

Tags: regular-languages, closure-properties

This is the question I am asked and I am currently proving it using proof by contradiction something like this:

- Let's take some language **L** which is non regular.
- Let's assume compliment of L i.e. $(L^c)$ is regular.
- Since we know that regular languages are closed under complementation, complementation of $(L^c)$, i.e. $(L^c)^c$ must be regular.
- Now  $(L^c)^c$ is  $L$ means $L$ is regular which contradicts the assumption.
- So, our assumption that $L^c$ is regular must be false.
- Hence, we can prove that $L^c$ is not regular.

Is this a correct approach to deduce?

Using same result I have to state true/false for the following two statements and support by giving proof.

- The class of non regular languages is closed under union.
- The class of non regular languages is closed under intersection.

How do I solve these two statements using the result above? Any hints would be helpful.

Thanks.

Comment: Your proof is correct. As for the next two statements: consider a language $L$ and its complement $L^c$. What can you say about their union/intersection?

Comment: Your first approach is completely correct. For the two remaining statement, you may want to use that $(A\cap B)^c = A^c \cup B^c$.

Comment: For intersection, you may think of two disjoint languages...

Comment: @Timot : Not quite sure how do I go through the approach you suggested. It asks for closed under union.

Comment: I'll give you a hint by saying that the class of non-regular languages is _not_ closed under union. Consider the language $\Sigma^{*}$, and think about what you showed in the first part of the question. The third part will fall out from a similar method. I personally would advise not using Timot's fact here, though it is still a useful tool to have available.

Comment: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/155353/755