# Regular language under intersection and complement confusion

Tags: formal-languages, regular-languages, automata, finite-automata

I know that regular languages are closed under closure properties. But, for example, we know if $L$ is regular, then its complement $L^\complement$ is also regular. If we have $L_1$ and $L_2$ as regular then $L_1 \cap L_2 = L_3$ makes $L_3$ regular. Now for the case of when $L$ is not regular, then its complement $L^\complement$ is also not regular. But when $L_1$ and $L_2$ are not regular then $L_1 \cap L_2 = L_3$ doesn't make $L_3$ not regular, why? does being closed mean for non regularity too?

Comment: Just a simple observation. Take any two language, be it non-regular, with no common strings. Their intersection must be $\emptyset$ which is regular. In general, I think the intersection can be quite arbitrary depending on the languages you are intersecting, so it can either result to a regular language or not. I am not 100% sure here so I am just making this a comment.

Comment: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/14462/755

Answer (score 1):

Non-regular languages are not closed under intersection.

Let $L_1 = \{aa^nb^n \mid n \ge 0\}$ and $L_2 = \{ba^nb^n \mid n \ge 0\}$.  Then $L_1 \cap L_2 = \emptyset$ is regular, but neither $L_1$ nor $L_2$ are regular.

Answer (score 0):

Intersection of 2 non regular languages means the languages [could be anything other than regular](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chomsky_hierarchy), and each class of languages have their own set of [closure properties](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/closure-properties-table-in-toc/). The problem of finding which class a language belongs to is undecidable.